# getColumnCount() and getPhysicalNumberOfCells methods are not invoking in my selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with .xlsx sheets in Selenium with the combi of Selenium-2.53.1 jar and Apache poi-3.17 jars. When i'm trying to get total number of columns by using these methods **getColumnCount()** and **getPhysicalNumberOfCells()** selenium is not invoking. underlining with red line error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to complete the tour and read the help topic [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks. Btw I didn't down vote

Comment: can you please show us the error details.

Comment: Fyi, Selenium and Apache poi are completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using code like below :

```
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet name");
        int noOfRows = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
        int noOfColumns = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
```

I am using Apache POI dependency :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

Hope that helps you:)

Comment: thank u ,i got it :)

Comment: can you please accept it as an answer.